# Ubuntu20 installation created a swap file default

Tags: server, swap

My Ubuntu20 server installation seems created a swap file swap.img default under "/" directory. I do also have a lvm swap partition
Is that a default behavior of ubuntu20 swap.img file ?
Is there a harm to keep both swap.img file as well as swap partition?

thanks.

Comment: Are both swap-file and -partition in use ? Run `swapon` in a terminal to verify. Default in newer Ubuntu installations is to use a swapfile.

Comment: So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 server system? and not a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server system (ie. *20 & 20.04 are different server products*)